# Working with date formats in Java and MySQL

Tags: javascript, mysql, date, laravel-5, type-conversion

Ok this is really bugging me.

I am developing a web app and I need to work with dates. When a date is displayed in a view, or whenever a date is entered into a form I need the format to be dd/mm/yyyy.

What data type do I choose for my SQL database columns which contain dates. 'Date' doesn't seem to work, do I use varchar?

But If I use varchar how do I use java script to perform arithmetic with dates.

Do I do some conversions server-side?

Please advise the best practices.

Also Im using laravel if theres any useful stuff already built in.

Comment: Have you looked at [Date Mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators)?. You can easily manage dates and formats in blade and php and even set a default format for a date using the `$dateFormat` property

Comment: maybe you could cast them as integers on the fly!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best practice to save the date in MySQL table as `date` field only. Which saves the date string in `YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss` format.

You need to make sure the following things.

1. Before inserting date into MySQL change the format of date string to `YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss`.
2. When you retrieve the date from database convert the date string from `YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss` to your desired format.

> You can use [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) class in Java to convert the dates
>   format. Use [format()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#format(java.util.Date,%20java.lang.StringBuffer,%20java.text.FieldPosition)) function to format the date in desired and
>   [parse()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#parse(java.lang.String,%20java.text.ParsePosition)) function to get the Java date object from string.

Reference: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Answer (score 2):

Date is the correct type to use in SQL DB.

To access the value use ISO date format `"YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"` .

You can create it from Java Date Object by using `toISOString()` method.

For easier time format conversion I can also recommend to check out [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/).

Answer (score 1):

you can use MySQL filed as datetime and also insert datetime format but when you will show then process it as you want as like 
when you insert value in table then you can also format it as like

```
<?php $mysqltime = date ("Y-m-d H:i:s", $phptime); ?>
```

where $phptime is your input variable

$str = suppose $row['date'] (mysql filed value)

```
date("d/m/Y", strtotime($str));
```

where $str your retrieve date filed

Answer (score 1):

You should use `varchar2` in `mysql`.

You can retrieve that `varchar` type date in `javascript` and create date object.

```
var d=dbdate;
var date = new Date(d);
```

And you can perform all `javascript` functions on date.

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript Date() object supports separate entries of date by:

```
    var date=new Date();
    var y=date.getFullYear();//4 digits
   var m=date.getMonth()+1;//0-11 digits, plus 1 for true state
   var d=date.getDate();//1-31
var dateSQL=y+'-'+m+'-'+d;//i.e 2016-07-25
```